# Find the Distinguished Name from a Bind DN

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I don't know if my question title even made sense - but let me explain.

When you do an LDAP query, you (apparently) are supposed to specify a DN in the Bind to "login" to the LDAP server. When I do this with slapd/OpenLDAP, the Bind DN is a normal DN like

> cn=brad,ou=users,dc=corp

or whatever. However, when I do this against [our corporate] Active Directory [server] - it wants a "Bind DN" to be like:

> CORP\brad

Which actually works. However, "CORP\brad" isn't really a DN in the ldap tree. In reality, "brad" exists as an object like "cn=brad,ou=users,dc=corp" - and this object has an "sAMAAccountName" attribute of "brad" (my actual username - changed here for simplification). I don't know if this is just "coincidence" - or if there could be others like this or what. How do you tell?

So - my quesion is - based on the DN/"Credentials" that were passed to the BIND, how can you determine what actual "Distingushed Name" the specified "Bind DN" equates to - when in AD - they don't appear to be one and of the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sAMAccountName is the username in Active Directory. If you search ldap for users with a samaccountname that matches your username, you can get the DN that way.

Comment: So  - I just strip away the "domain" portion of the username?

Comment: I'll give you the credit. What I discovered was that I was actually using a "Global Catalog" server - which means more than one "tree" is in it - and thus more than one sAMAccountName can be in it. So I used the sAMAAccountName, with some more logic to make sure that from the domain name, I had the correct tree specified as the search base.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps extract the DN from "ADsPath". You can obtain this as an attribute/field in your program after you bind to AD.

The DIT on AD and your other directory powered by OpenLDAP may not be the same, rendering different DNs.

Comment: I can't find that attribute/field anywhere in the directory.

Comment: It's actually not an attribute. It's the fully qualified LDAP URL that can reference an entry in the directory. For LDAP-based directories, the DN is usually the part after the host:port element of the URL. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can retrieve ADsPath as a property of your directory connection object. If you're using ADSI/ADO, it can also be returned as a column/field in the SQL result set. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: One more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: My question is a bit more basic: I am given user credentials "domain\username" and "password". I need to authenticate this user against the AD server, and then figure out what their DN is, so I can look up their attributes. Question is - from the "domain\username" string - how do I figure out what DN to use?